# Ember - data is nested n levels deep, want findBy in route to work from URL

Tags: ember.js

New to Ember (will be obvious), but I have an issue that I think others will run across while learnging. Basically I have incoming data that is a tree hierarchy of tags. The app basically represents a node of the tree by showing any children. Click a child, and the display is replaced with a list of their children and so on. Simple.

The problem comes when routing from the URL (manual refresh or whatever):

If a user were to type in the URL "#/tags/0", the application is able to find and serve the list of the children of tag with 'id' 0 (because it is top level, I assume). But if the user types in an URL with the id of a n-deep child, the findBy method fails to find the right node in the data.

Is there a recursive version of findBy or something like that?

Here's the relevant lines and some dummy data to illustrate what I mean about the hierarchy.

```
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('tags', function () {
        this.resource('tag', { path: ':tag_id' });
    });
});

App.TagsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return tags;
    }
});

App.TagRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return tags.findBy('id', params.tag_id);
    }
});

var tags = [{
                weight: "plus size3",
                untaggable: true,
                id: '0',
                label : "Existing Tags",
                children: [{    
                        id: "2",
                        weight: "plus size7",
                        label: "take-out"
                    },
                    {   id: "3",
                        weight: "plus size9",
                        label: "busy environment"
                    },
                    {   id: "4",
                        weight: "minus size9",
                        label: "casual-attire environment"
                    },
                    {   id: "5",
                        weight: "minus size0",
                        label: "classical-crossover-music"
                    },
                    {   id: "6",
                        weight: "plus size0",
                        label: "knowledgeable"
                    },
                    {   id: "7",
                        weight: "plus size3",
                        label: "busy environment"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                untaggable: true,
                id: '1',
                weight: "minus size9",
                label: "Add More Tags",
                children: [{
                        untaggable: true,
                        id: '1111',
                        weight: "plus size9",
                        label: "interior",
                        children: [{    
                            id: '8',
                            weight: "minus size9",
                            label: "modern",
                        },{     
                            id: '9',
                            weight: "plus size3",
                            label: "classic",
                        },{     
                            id: '10',
                            weight: "plus size3",
                            label: "dive",
                        }]
                    },{ 
                        untaggable: true,
                        id: '2222',
                        weight: "minus size9",
                        label: "exterior",
                        children: [{        
                            id: '11',
                            weight: "minus size9",
                            label: "elegent exterior",
                            children: [{        
                                id: '111',
                                weight: "minus size9",
                                label: "boroque exterior",
                            },{     
                                id: '112',
                                weight: "plus size0",
                                label: "expensive exterior",
                            }]
                        },{     
                            id: '12',
                            label: "dingy exterior",
                            children: [{        
                                id: '121',
                                weight: "plus size0",
                                label: "shabby exterior",
                            },{     
                                id: '122',
                                weight: "minus size6",
                                label: "dirty exterior",
                            }]
                        },{     
                            id: '13',
                            weight: "plus size6",
                            label: "discrete exterior"
                        }]
                    },{ 
                        untaggable: true,
                        id: '3333',
                        weight: "minus size6",
                        label: "pricing",
                        children: [{        
                            id: '14',
                            weight: "plus size3",
                            label: "$0-10 per person",
                        },{     
                            id: '15',
                            weight: "minus size0",
                            label: "$10-20 per person",
                        },{     
                            id: '16',
                            weight: "plus size9",
                            label: "$20-30 per person",
                        },{     
                            id: '17',
                            weight: "minus size3",
                            label: "$30-40 per person",
                        },{     
                            id: '18',
                            weight: "plus size9",
                            label: "$40-50 per person",
                        },{     
                            id: '19',
                            weight: "minus size0",
                            label: "$50+ per person",
                        }]
                    },{ 
                        untaggable: true,
                        id: '4444',
                        weight: "plus size1",
                        label: "features",
                        children: [{
                            id: '20',
                            weight: "minus size0",
                            label: "beer-buckets"
                        },{
                            id: '21',
                            weight: "plus size8",
                            label: "big-screen-tv"},
                        {
                            id: '22',
                            weight: "zero size7",
                            label: "comedy"},
                        {
                            id: '23',
                            weight: "plus size9",
                            label: "drink-specials"},
                        {
                            id: '24',
                            weight: "zero size2",
                            label: "games",
                            children: [
                            {
                                id: '241',
                                weight: "minus size0",
                                label: "darts"},
                            {
                                id: '242',
                                weight: "plus size9",
                                label: "pool-table"}]},
                        {
                            id: '25',
                            weight: "plus size0",
                            label: "growlers"},
                        {
                            id: '26',
                            weight: "plus size3",
                            label: "happy-hour"},
                        {
                            id: '27',
                            weight: "minus size0",
                            label: "music"}]
                    },{ 
                        untaggable: true,
                        id: '5555',
                        weight: "plus size3",
                        label: "staff",
                        children: [{
                            id: '30',
                            weight: "minus size0",
                            label: "argumentative"},
                        {
                            id: '31',
                            weight: "plus size8",
                            label: "attentive"},
                        {
                            id: '32',
                            weight: "zero size5",
                            label: "available"},
                        {
                            id: '33',
                            weight: "plus size3",
                            label: "capable"},
                        {
                            id: '34',
                            weight: "minus size9",
                            label: "careless"},
                        {
                            id: '35',
                            weight: "plus size0",
                            label: "chatty"},
                        {
                            id: '36',
                            weight: "minus size6",
                            label: "cheerful"},
                        {
                            id: '37',
                            weight: "plus size3",
                            label: "competent"},
                        {
                            id: '38',
                            weight: "minus size0",
                            label: "considerate"},
                        {
                            id: '39',
                            weight: "minus size3",
                            label: "easy-going"},
                        {
                            id: '40',
                            weight: "plus size0",
                            label: "efficient"},
                        {
                            id: '41',
                            weight: "plus size3",
                            label: "engaging"},
                        {
                            id: '42',
                            weight: "plus size8",
                            label: "experienced"},
                        {
                            id: '43',
                            weight: "minus size1",
                            label: "friendly"}]
                }]
        }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't a recursive version of `findBy`.  The "standard" way to handle something like this is to store your objects in a flat data structure: either a hash with object IDs as keys, or an array of objects.

Your tree of tags is a somewhat arbitrary/unique data structure, so you have two options:

1. Represent your data in a more standard way, thereby allowing you to use the standard functions for arrays and objects.finder function.
2. Keep your data in tree format, but write your own recursive

If you go with option 2, what you want is something like this:

```
function findTagById(tags, id) {
  var potentialMatch, match;

  for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    potentialMatch = tags[i];

    if (potentialMatch.id === id) {
      return potentialMatch;
    }

    if (potentialMatch.children) {
      match = findTagById(potentialMatch.children, id);

      if (match) {
        return match;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In your example, the tag data is hard-coded into the app. However, in the real world, the vast majority of apps built using Ember consume data from received from a web server, usually via a JSON API. Ember Data has all sorts of customizable serializers responsible for taking potentially oddly-structured data received from the server and transforming it into individual models that can be included in a flat array. I recommend making use of Ember Data if you can.

Comment: Thanks so much! It definitely sounds like I should go with Ember Data to transform it. In the mean time, I'll try your function too.  Hat tip!